# Android error in getSupportFragmentManager

Tags: java, android

I am really new to Java and I am trying to create a Google Map in a fragment however I am receiving the error: "'replace(int, androidx.fragment.app.Fragment)' in 'androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction' cannot be applied to '(int, android.app.Fragment)'" when I try open the fragment in MainActivity. Does anyone know what my problem is?

My code for MainActivity.java is:

```
package com.example.mapinfragment;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Initialise fragment
        Fragment fragment = new MapFragment();

        //Open fragment
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_layout,fragment)
                .commit();
    }
}
```

And for activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/frame_layout" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And for fragment_map.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MapFragment">
    
    <fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/google_map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And for MapFragment.java

```
package com.example.mapinfragment;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Initialise view
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);

        //Initialise map fragment
        SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)
                getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.google_map);

        //Async map
        supportMapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapReady(@NonNull GoogleMap googleMap) {
                //When map is loaded
                googleMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onMapClick(@NonNull LatLng latLng) {
                        //When clicked on map
                        //Initialise marker options
                        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
                        //Set position of marker
                        markerOptions.position(latLng);
                        //Set title of marker
                        markerOptions.title(latLng.latitude + " : " + latLng.longitude);
                        //Remove all markers
                        googleMap.clear();
                        //Animating the zoom to marker
                        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                                latLng,10
                        ));
                        //Add marker on map
                        googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        //Return view
        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mixing up old platform fragments (`android.app.Fragment`) with up-to-date AndroidX support library fragments (`androidx.fragment.app.Fragment`).

In your main activity, replace `import android.app.Fragment` with the corresponding androidx import. Also delete `import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment` to use your own `MapFragment` instead.

Comment: Thank you laalto! I have attempted this but then I get a "cannot resolve symbol 'Fragment'" error. So I tried adding "implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'" to my dependencies to address this but then I get another error: "Version 28 (intended for Android Pie and below) is the last version of the legacy support library, so we recommend that you migrate to the AndroidX libraries when using Android Q and moving forward. The IDE can help with this: Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX...".

Comment: implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment:1.5.4"

Comment: laalto you genius! Thank you so much for your help and your patience explaining it to me! To summarise for anyone else following, 3 things needed to be changed: 1) In MainActivity - I replaced "import android.app.Fragment" with "import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment". 2) I deleted "import.com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" 3) Under dependencies (in build.gradle(:app) - I added "implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment:1.5.4'"